# How to dynamically assign value to data in object?

Tags: c++, dynamic

I have a structure, e.g.

```
struct Test
{
    std::string a;
    std::string b;
    std::string c;
};
```

In another part of project I want to assign value to one od three values in structure( I want to edit it).

It is possible to do something like that:

```
void foo (std::string newValue, std::string nameOfStructMember)
{
    for(auto & it : test) //in another part of project exist std::vector<Test> test;
    {
        it.nameOfStructMember= newValue;
    }
}
```

And e.g. in `main.cpp`:

```
foo("This is my new value", "a");
```

Comment: No, you cannot do that in C++, it is not an interpreter. You can write code that would assign a value to a member based on a string, but you will have to provide member names manually. If you need to assign value only this way then you do not need members, just use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`

Comment: Why would you ever need something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do exactly that. What you want is to resolve the adress of a member at runtime via it's name. This is called reflection and not possible in C++.

However you can do something quite similiar with [member pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_data_members).

```
void foo(const std::string &newValue, std::string Test::*member)
{
    for(auto & it : test)
    {
        it.*member = newValue;
    }
}
```

`member` essentially holds the offset of some member of `Test`, such that `it.*member` will access that member. You can call this function with

```
foo("This is my new value", &Test::a); //or &Test::b and so on
```

---

The main drawback here is obviously, that `&Foo::a` needs to be known at compile time. But you can easily use a `std::unordered_map` to map actual member names to member pointers:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string Test::*> mapping {
    {"a", &Test::a},
    // and so on
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you mean something like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Test
{
    std::string a;
    std::string b;
    std::string c;
};

void f( std::vector<Test> &v, std::string Test::*p, const char *s )
{
    for ( auto &t : v )
    {
        t.*p = s;
    }        
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<Test> v( 2 );

    std::string Test::*p = &Test::a;;

    f( v, p, "A" );

    p = &Test::b;;

    f( v, p, "B" );

    p = &Test::c;;

    f( v, p, "C" );

    for ( const auto &t : v )
    {        
        std::cout << t.a << ' ' << t.b << ' ' << t.c;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }        
}
```

The program output is

```
A B C
A B C
```